Python Pandas read CSV file where dd/mm/yyyy date is shown as mm/dd
I've got a CSV file where it keeps the date column in the format of DD/MM, however, when I click the cell, the real value is in the format of DD/MM/YYYY.
For example:
28/03; 182409; 7579480; 1000; 1100; 1200; 1300
28/03; 220000; 0480000; 1000; 1100; 1200; 1300
28/03; 220000; 0760000; 1000; 1100; 1200; 1300

The value 28/03 in the first column is actually 28/03/2024. Please note that the year is not always 2024, but could be any possible year.
I think I can make a copy of the CSV file as XLSX and use openpyxl to convert the column to DD/MM/YYYY.
But I'm wondering if there's a way to do it directly using Pandas?

"CSV file" / "when I click the cell" -> you can't click a cell in a CSV file, this is just Excel interpreting the string automatically to a date, nothing to do with pandas

I'd suggest you add the year directly to values as you read it and then pass it on to Pandas to avoid problems relating to guess work.

You can ask pandas to parse the dates when reading a CSV with read_csv:
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, sep=';', parse_dates=[0],
                 date_format='%d/%m')

However, in your case, since the year is missing you would get:
           0       1        2     3     4     5     6
0 1900-03-28  182409  7579480  1000  1100  1200  1300
1 1900-03-28  220000   480000  1000  1100  1200  1300
2 1900-03-28  220000   760000  1000  1100  1200  1300

A workaround would be to convert it after import with to_datetime:
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, sep=';')
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0]+'/2024', format='%d/%m/%Y')

Output:
           0       1        2     3     4     5     6
0 2024-03-28  182409  7579480  1000  1100  1200  1300
1 2024-03-28  220000   480000  1000  1100  1200  1300
2 2024-03-28  220000   760000  1000  1100  1200  1300


Thanks for the answer, mozway. Sorry I didn't mention it in the original post that the year is not always 2024. That's why I'm struggling.

@ChangeMyName how do you know how to define the year if it not always 2024?
